# Auto-generated ids for facelets components

Tags: java, jsf, jstl, facelets

We use facelets to create some custom ajaxy components.  One of the behaviours we would like to mimic from the default components is that an id is optional, and an id is generated if it is not passed.  I can already do it like this:

```
<ui:composition ...>
  <div class="myComponent" id="#{jsfSupport.generateId(id)}">
     ...
  </div>
</ui:composition>
```

I use JBoss el to call a support method (could use el functions as well):

```
public class JsfSupport {

  public String generateId(String id) {

    if (id==null || "".equals(id){
  return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().createUniqueId();
    }
    return id;
  }

}
```

The problem is that if I need that id somewhere in my javascript code in the component, I need to retrieve it again.  So I thought I could do the following:

```
<ui:composition ...>
  <c:set var="id" value="#{jsfSupport.generateId(id)}" />
  <div class="myComponent" id="#{id}">
     ...
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('#{id}');
  </script>
</ui:composition>
```

But that doesn't work.  The id gets regenerated anyway and I get two different ones.
Any ideas on what would be the ideal way to do this?

Comment: Can I ask you about how you would access that generated "id" from the page, where you included/used the above ajax components? For Ex: If you have to reRender the custom ajax component, how would you do that?

Comment: @bchetty You can't.  If you need to rerender it, you need to pass in an Id.  The autogenerated ID is only in the case there is no external interaction with the component.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<c:set>` in Facelets means aliasing, not an assignment like in JSP. So every use of `#{id}` is translated into a separate call to `#{jsfSupport.generateId(id)}`, which results in problems you describe.

You could write your own version of `<c:set>` tag which would evaluate the passed expression only once, and save the returned value:

```
public class SetOnceHandler extends TagHandler
{
    private TagAttribute var;
    private TagAttribute value;

    public SetOnceHandler(TagConfig cfg) 
    {
        super(cfg);
        value = getRequiredAttribute("value");
        var = getRequiredAttribute("var");
    }

    public void apply(FaceletContext ctx, UIComponent parent) 
    {
        ctx.setAttribute(var.getValue(ctx), value.getObject(ctx));
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks.  I'm amazed there's no out-of-the-box thing for this...

Comment: I am also facing exactly the same issue. Could you please explain what all needs to be done to have this handler in place?